# Connect to CRM and get data

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm writing an ASP.NET app that should connect to dynamics CRM and fetch the contacts info. In the view it should return a list of the contacts with their info. There is some data in the testing CRM I'm provided with but I can't get the entities (e.g. table name and its columns), so I can't create my models in VS, since I don't know what props to put there.

Is there a way to get the entites with the code, or how can this problem be solved?

I've tried early-bound generator, and it won't work. I tried with ADO.NET entity data model but doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you connect directly to the dynamics database at all?

Comment: I can connect to the CRM via browser and connection string in web.config, but I don't have anything about database.

Comment: @justSome_randomGuy If you have a connection string that works then you should have the needed information to connect to the database and see the CRM data structure.

Comment: So you have the OptionSets.cs and XRM.cs from the generator? You've created a sqlconnection to the CRM server and implemented the Create, Retrieve, RetrieveMultiple and Update methods?

Comment: @DavidYenglin I don't have those files because the generetaor didn't work.

Comment: without those files you won't have access to the CRM schema in your project

Comment: @DavidYenglin I know, and i don't have those files

Comment: @EdneyHolder If you colud be so kind to tell me how/where could I see the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

In order to actually work with the CRM entities you're going to need to configure your project to work with an [Organization Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/quick-start-org-service-console-app?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) (Might need a different tutorial depending on CRM version) that connects to your CRM instance.

Afterwards, like David Yenglin was explaining, you should be able to use methods like [`IOrganizationService.Retrieve(String, Guid, ColumnSet)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg326164(v%3Dcrm.8)) which allows you to retrieve a record or [`IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg326157(v%3Dcrm.8)) which allows you to retrieve multiple records. In your case, I think you just need the Retrieve method.

Another way you can access the data is through the [CRM Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/mt593051%28v%3Dcrm.8%29) (which I have less experience with) which would allow you to [query the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg334767(v%3Dcrm.8)) from CRM.

There's a ton of great examples of different scenarios over at Microsoft's github repo, [PowerApps-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples). I'd recommend checking it out later when you get your project configured.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check it out.

Comment: @justSome_randomGuy any luck?

Comment: @justSome_randomGuy Glad to hear, take it easy

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2018/02/03/step-by-step-to-connect-dynamics-365-crm-online-v9-x-using-c-console-application/) will give you step by step way to connect to CRM.

Once you get sucessfully connected to CRM, try below code which will give you complete information about all the contact Records.

```
try
 {
 ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
 clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "<ProvideUserName>@<ProvideYourOrgName>.onmicrosoft.com";
 clientCredentials.UserName.Password = "<ProvideYourPassword>";

// For Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement V9.X, set Security Protocol as TLS12
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
// Get the URL from CRM, Navigate to Settings -> Customizations -> Developer Resources
// Copy and Paste Organization Service Endpoint Address URL
organizationService = (IOrganizationService)new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri("https://<ProvideYourOrgName>.api.<CRMRegion>.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"),
 null, clientCredentials, null);

if (organizationService != null)
 {
 Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)organizationService.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;

if (userid != Guid.Empty)
 {
 Console.WriteLine("Connection Established Successfully...");
 // your logic here.
                    queryExpressionTest(organizationService);


 }
 }
 else
 {
 Console.WriteLine("Failed to Established Connection!!!");
 }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 Console.WriteLine("Exception caught - " + ex.Message); 
 }
 Console.ReadKey();
 }
        private static void queryExpressionTest(IOrganizationService organizationService)
        {
            QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
            qe.EntityName = "contact";
            qe.ColumnSet= new ColumnSet(true); // this will give you all the columns of contact record
            //qe.ColumnSet= new ColumnSet("name", "accountnumber"); you could also restrict which particualr attributes you wish to retrieve from contact record.

            EntityCollection coll = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
            foreach (Entity cont in coll.Entities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name of contact: " + cont.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname"));
                Console.WriteLine("Email of contact " + cont.GetAttributeValue<string>("email"));
                /**
                Now you can add all the attributes you wish to show
                */
            }

        }
```